# Just how much more precise is `Comparable` than it appears?

Tags: java

The `Comparable` interface looks like

```
interface Comparable<T>
{
  public int compareTo(T other);
...
}
```

This does not inherently say anything about the relationship between an implementation of `Comparable<T>` and the type `T`. The text of the Java spec seems to suggest that an implementation of `Comparable<T>` should always be a subclass of `T`, but it doesn't explicitly say so, as far as I can tell. Is it supposed to? Also, if the implementation, `A`, of `Comparable<T>` is a *strict* subclass of `T`, then the antisymmetry rule *seems* to suggest that `T` must be an implementation of `Comparable<Ap>` for some superclass, `Ap`, of `A`. This is a rather stringent requirement. In fact, it's stringent enough that I don't think it's generally possible to do it unless the two classes are constructed specially for the purpose. Any thoughts? Am I missing something, or is this one weird interface?

Comment: Is Google down or something? The contract is all in the [javadoc for `Comparable#compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T))

Comment: @Bohemian, I've read that several times. It doesn't exactly answer the question, because it doesn't say when those comparisons must be available. It's perfectly clear that if a.compareTo(b) and b.compareTo(a) are both valid, then they must have a certain relationship. But when must they be valid?

Comment: I'm confused as to what the question is. If you pass in a subclass of `T` it's the same as anything else; it will (without downcasting) be treated as a `T` inside the method. If you desire a subclass not to be considered equal under any condition, you do an `instanceof` check (which you will find is a very common thing in `compareTo()` implementations).

Comment: Actually ... scratch that last bit. I had `equals()` stuck in my head for some reason. The same would still apply re: `instanceOf` but you'd need to decide what the ordering would be if that's *really* what you wanted.

Comment: @BrianRoach, I suppose I'm having trouble figuring out what use there could be in having `SomeClass` implement `Comparable <SomeOtherClass>` when the rules seem to restrict it so much. One possibility is that instances of a subclass can be compared to instances of its superclass particularly efficiently, I suppose, but that seems relatively unlikely. Does Java just not have a way to express, in the interface, that the implementation type is the same as the type that's passed in?

Comment: Huh, I think I actually misunderstood your Q then (I'll delete my answer). There is no point of implementing `Comparable<SomeOtherClass>`, no. Generics in Java are really just compile time type checking (for the most part); specifying `class Foo implements Comparable<Foo>` just gives you that type checking for the `compareTo()` method.

Comment: @BrianRoach, don't delete your answer; I think it's useful. I guess what troubles me is that if you look at the `Comparator` interface, it does just what in says on the box. `Comparable` does less, and it takes quite a bit of work to figure out just how much less (I still don't feel like I have an entirely clear sense of it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This interface was there long before the generics were introduced and originally looked like

`public int compareTo(Object other);`

This is still what it looks like after compilation into byte code. With addition of generics this interface was modified to provide some basic type safety.

If I understand your question right, you're asking "What stops me from doing this?"

`class SomeClass implements Comparable<SomeUnrelatedClass>`

Well, nothing. Back when the `compareTo` method worked with Objects you had to think about which type(s) the `compareTo` would be useful for and it's still the case with the updated interface.